# IIS handler returning "the connection was reset" error

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler

There are two websites under the Default Web Site in IIS 6. The same code is deployed to both. An asp.net 4.0 web application with an httphandler.

On both websites the the mappings in the configuration settings are added. 
The web.config files for both are also configured.

```
<handlers>
  <add name="CAHandler" verb="*" path="*.handler" type="Namespace.CAHandler" />
  <add name="CAHandler2" verb="*" path="calink.dll" type="Namespace.CAHandler" />
</handlers>
```

On the one website the handler returns "The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." error. Firefox error message.
Only difference i see with websites on IIS is the working one has the option - Under the directory tab - The content for this source should come from options, the working site has "The designated directory" option selected and a relative path to folder.
The non working one has "A directory located on this computer" and the path is absolute.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have anything in the event log ? Start -> Run -> eventvwr

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar Not seeing anything in the event log.